# What if my gravatar already is a hat?

Tags: support, winterbash

Well, as the title says... My gravatar already was a hat, a fedora, if I'm correct, before hat-mania broke loose here.

Is this going to be like "Yo dawg ..."? Or do I have to change my gravatar to be able to receive a hat?

Comment: There is no such thing as too many hats. HATS ON ALL THE THINGS.

Comment: Wear ALL THE HATS!

Comment: I don't always wear hats, but when I do, I prefer Dos Sombreros.

Comment: I stand with you, in doubly-haberdashed solidarity.

Comment: Certainly if a helmet can wear a hat, a hat can wear a hat.

Comment: I love that this devolved into memes. :D

Comment: @Aarthi I was hoping to have some semi-related fun. Mission accomplished :D

Comment: Hurr hurr hurr! :P

Comment: hatception.....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not the only one with recursive avatar problems.

[image]

Comment: Accepted as the only guy having pretty much the same 'problem' :D

Comment: ahahahahaha you have no idea how hard me and @davidFullerton laughed when that got made!

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The [towering pillar of hats](http://tf2wiki.net/wiki/Towering_Pillar_of_Hats) laughs at your plight:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Hat-wearing knows no bounds.

If you choose to participate in Hatdash, you'll make Xzibit proud for sure.

Comment: :D I'll try, that's for sure :P

Comment: hats all the way!

Comment: @alexanderpas hats all the way *down*!